# How can I nest an vector index match function in an if statement? (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have the following vector function:

```
{=INDEX(Key!$K$2:$K$25,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Key!$K$2:$K$25,V5)),0))}
```

This function returns what is in `Key!$K$2:$K$25` if V5 is a match. This formula works. I would like to also make the function return, "Not Found", if the value searched for is not present in `Key!$K$2:$K$25`. I have tried the following, but it doesn't work. Could someone help?

```
{=IF(MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Key!$K$2:$K$25,V3)),0),INDEX(Key!$K$2:$K$25,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Key!$K$2:$K$25,V3)),0)),"Not Found")}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply merge your `=INDEX(Key!$K$2:$K$25,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Key!$K$2:$K$25,V5)),0))` with `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Key!$K$2:$K$25,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Key!$K$2:$K$25,V5)),0)),"Not found")
```